# How to set up Apache Solr with facets so that it uses a front page search form?

Tags: search

So I am working on my first mid sized D7 projects and it needs some rather advanced searching capabilities (at least advanced for me). I've installed Solr, created a server and an index with the Search API, and created a search page.
So far so good... everything works according to what you'd expect, and it even has facets, which is something I really wanted for this site. The problem is that this seems to be pretty much my ceiling... and I would like to change some things. For instance:

1. I would like to be able to search through my indexed taxonomies. Right now I can only search the node titles and descriptions and I have a bunch of taxonomies which is what I really want to search through.
2. I would like the users to be able to search from a search form in my home. Right now the core search is all I have in my front page, and if I want to use the Solr server I have to go to my search page. Ideally I want the user to enter a search term in the search form, to be redirected to the results page, and just there for him to see all the facets to further filter the results... linkedin style.

How would you guys accomplish something like that?

Edit:

Seems it seems I haven't stated clearly what I intend to do I'll try to upload some pics regarding point 1:

admin/config/search/search_api/index/node_search/fields

These are the fields I choose to be indexed!
[image: These are the fields I choose to be indexed]

admin/config/search/search_api/page/search/edit
[image: If you see I can only choose "Title" and "description" from the fields to search from... so if I search for a taxonomy term which is not in any title or description, I get nothing]

If you see I can only choose "Title" and "description" from the fields to search from... so if I search for a taxonomy term which is not in any title or description, I get nothing. I would like to make the taxonomies in the first picture searchable... which is why I indexed them in the first place.

Edit 2:

I've finally managed to get the core search form to work with Solr following this tut(http://web3us.com/drupal6/how-create-web-site-handbook/apache-solr-drupal/apache-solr-3-drupal-7-turtorial-screen-shots) but I still don't know how to display the fields I want in the search results. Right now the results look like this:

[image]

And I would like each of them to look as the Teasers I've configured in my "Restaurant" content type (which are the nodes that I've set Solr to index)

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) and [Search API Solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr)? (I've never used them, so can't speak to how good they may be.)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using and having problems with...

Comment: Sorry, missed that in Q

Comment: I have deleted my answer, as your screenshots now speak a very different story than I gleaned from your original question. Not sure why your fields are not showing in the search pages. but for the second question, see the issue queue http://drupal.org/node/1235026

Comment: mmm... do you know what this could be all about? >SearchApiException: The "Facets block" display cannot be used with a view for Content. Please only use this display with base tables representing search indexes. in SearchApiViewsFacetsBlockDisplay->getFieldOptions() (line 123 of /Users/muayguy/www/rhys/sites/all/modules/search_api/contrib/search_api_views/includes/display_facet_block.inc). Every time I try to make a "fitting search view" I get that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question #1:** 
Go to admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings and select 'Bias'.  There you can set up the weights next to the terms you want to search through.  Perhaps they're on 'Omit' or something like that...

**Question #2**: Go to the search settings page and make Apache solr search be your default search.  That way, when users type in keywords in your regular search form, they will automatically use your apachesolr search.
admin/config/search/settings

[image]

Let us know if that worked for you!

Comment: Thanks, I eventually got it to work. Do you know how to change the search results thought? To actually display the teasers instead of just the titles and the small part of the text where the keywords (searched terms) were found?

Comment: Well, if you go to your content type and go to the "Manage Display" tab, look at the 'Custom Display Settings' section and expand it (it's collapsed by default).  If you check the 'Search result' checkbox and save, it should let you customize what fields are returned in the search results.  I've never tried this, but it seems promising!

Comment: http://is.gd/e7fBlh

Comment: .... but it doesn't seem to be using that display in my search results... :(

Comment: Ah, I see.  This may be a big topic to discuss in the comments, and others who know better may not see these comments.  I think it would help to start a fresh question on theming apache solr search results (since it seems this will probably require theming) and see if that gets the discussion going.  Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: no problem...for what I've found so far it seems it could be a D7 bug (http://drupal.org/node/1166114)